# Create an annotation that has a specific @ConditionalOnProperty?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My plan is to create an annotation that if I put that on a class, the class will be a bean only if the @ConditionalOnProperty is true.

I have this:

`@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)`

I want to create some beans (controllers / services) only if the `backend-auth.enabled=true` exists in the `application.properties` file. Now at the moment I have this:

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class FirstController {}

@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class SecondController{}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class FirstService {}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class SecondService{}
```

As you can see I am reusing the `@ConditionalOnProperty` part and in case I want to change the `prefix`, `value` or `havingValue` values, then I have to change it at 4 places and it can be missed if not paying attention...

I am thinking about creating an annotation that contains the `@ConditionalOnProperty` and use this custom annotation on my `FirstController`, `SecondController`, `FirstService`, `SecondService`.

I want to end up with something like this:

```
@RestController
@BackendAuthEnabled
public class FirstController {}

@RestController
@BackendAuthEnabled
public class SecondController{}

@Service
@BackendAuthEnabled
public class FirstService {}

@Service
@BackendAuthEnabled
public class SecondService{}
```

Comment: Did you test it?  According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19837 it should work as meta-annotation

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "backend-auth", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BackendAuthEnabled {
}
```

(Thanks Wim for the link)